# Android Studio contain other Studio reference in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Android Studio in Ubuntu 16.10. it is crashed after i install other android studio in my system And Old studio is remove but whenever i start studio it is detect old configuration it is run old sdk. not run newly install studio.
any one can help me solve out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto,

`~home/yourusername`

Turn on "**Show Hidden Files**" and delete the previous Android Studio configurations folder. The folder should look similar to this,

```
.AndroidStudio2.3
```

Go to the Android Studio installation folder and make sure the old and newly installed folder have a different name. Now run the app and configure it according to your need.

Comment: Thanks,
 I done Already that but still i am facing same issue

Comment: Do you want to use the updated Android SDK or just the Updated Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio crash due to power failure . i am not doing studio or sdk update

Comment: Can you try downloading a completely new Android Studio from google?